# NodeJS redirector.google.com return 403 error

Tags: node.js

I want to download videos from google drive. 
I was got video links from google drive (redirector.google.com)

redirector links redirecting another links in google. Like 3-7--n-y-mm.googlevideo.com.

I'm using download-from-url package from nodejs for download videos.

I'm getting this error. How can i fix ?

note : If i visit redirector link in google chrome, its redirecting me to true link.

http://prntscr.com/dzslpp

here codes :

http://prntscr.com/dzszxp

Text of error and codes.
Error :

```
downloading...
STARTO
https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=50a591ac19de97bd&itag=22&source=webdrive&requiressl=yes&ttl=transient&mm=31&mn=sn-5hne6n7e&ms=au&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LmFtczE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=22&mime=video/mp4&lmt=1485237105908527&mt=1485276323&ip=46.166.148.148&ipbits=8&expire=1485290986&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cttl%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cmime%2Clmt&signature=075A6977C5DA2232BDF6325E2B7DE659DF910283.97EFF36FEF6ED1CDD6FFDE5FB81E576C6F8C3564&key=ck2&app=explorer
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\diziBot\diziBot\exp.js:77
          throw err;
          ^

Error: Server responded with error code : 403
```

Code :

```
var url = "https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=50a591ac19de97bd&itag=22&source=webdrive&requiressl=yes&ttl=transient&mm=31&mn=sn-5hne6n7e&ms=au&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LmFtczE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=22&mime=video/mp4&lmt=1485237105908527&mt=1485276323&ip=46.166.148.148&ipbits=8&expire=1485290986&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cttl%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cmime%2Clmt&signature=075A6977C5DA2232BDF6325E2B7DE659DF910283.97EFF36FEF6ED1CDD6FFDE5FB81E576C6F8C3564&key=ck2&app=explorer";

 var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
      console.log("STARTO");
      console.log(response.responseUrl);
      const downloader = require('download-from-url');

      downloader(response.responseUrl, function(err, infos, headers) {
        if(err)
          throw err;
        console.log("Finish");
        uploadGoogle(dizi_adi_up);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Please paste the code and error here instead of the link to images. That would help to debug and test your code.

Comment: @Jeet i did ...

Comment: i need help please....